# How to access json schema info in SparkDataset Api when using plain map/reduce functions?

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given there is a dataset of messages, defined by following code:

```
case class Message(id: Int, value: String)

  var messages = Seq(
  (0, """{"action":"update","timestamp":"2017-10-05T23:01:19Z"}"""),
  (1, """{"action":"update","timestamp":"2017-10-05T23:01:19Z"}""")
).toDF("id", "value").as[Message]


var schema = new StructType().add("action", StringType).add("timestamp", TimestampType)

var res = messages.select(
  from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema)
)

+------------------------------------+
|jsontostructs(CAST(value AS STRING))|
+------------------------------------+
|                [update,2017-10-0...|
|                [update,2017-10-0...|
```

What is the best way to access the schema information in a plain map function. The function itself returns a row which has lost all the Type infos. In order to reach to the values one has to specify the type again e.g

```
res.head().getStruct(0).getValuesMap[TimestampType](Seq("timestamp"))
=> Map[String,org.apache.spark.sql.types.TimestampType] = Map(timestamp -> 2017-10-06 01:01:19.0)
```

or

```
res.head().getStruct(0).getString(0)
 => res20: String = update
```

Is there some better way to access the raw json data without spark sql aggregation functions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule of thumb:

- To use collection API (`map`, `flatMap`, `mapPartitions`, `groupByKey`, etc.) use strongly typed API - define record type (case class works the best) which reflects the schema and use `Encoders` to convert things back and forth:

  ```
  case class Value(action: String, timestamp: java.sql.Timestamp)
  case class ParsedMessage(id: Int, value: Option[Value])

  messages.select(
    $"id", from_json(col("value").cast("string"), schema).alias("value")
  ).as[ParsedMessage].map(???)
  ```
- With `Dataset[Row]` stay with high level SQL / `DataFrame` API (`select`, `where`, `agg`, `groupBy`)